# pass multiple values using select_tag where only a single value is displayed Ruby on Rails form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, hashmap, html-select

I have a hash called @records_hash which consists of 3 arrays: @records_hash["EVENT_DESCR"], @records_hash["EVENT_ID"], and @records_hash["PROCESSS_ID"]

I want the user to be able to select from a dropdown the event they would like to view and pass the corresponding values to the next page.

I want the user to see the EVENT_DESCR when they are using the dropdown, but I would like to pass the EVENT_ID and the PROCESS_ID to the next page.

Currently, I have a form that looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'options', :action => 'sort', :type => 'event', :page => 1}, :method => 'get') do %>
    <%= select_tag 'event_descr', options_for_select(@records_hash["EVENT_DESCR"]) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

This form successfully lists out the EVENT_DESCR's in a dropdown format and sends the EVENT_DESCR to the next page.

How would I go about sending the EVENT_ID and the PROCESS_ID with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
# the values are whatever you want to pass. I'm just doing an array of arrays with EVENT_ID first.
<% values = @records_hash["EVENT_ID"].zip(@records_hash["PROCESSS_ID"]) %>
<% opts = options_for_select(@records_hash["EVENT_DESCR"].zip(values)) %>
<%= select_tag 'event_descr', opts %>
```

Comment: This is what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) - you may need to modify your hashes to a collection of objects but this will make your code more readable. Probably a class `XXEvent` with `id`, `descr` and `process_id` as properties.